# Can I push my matrix for one time for static objects in OpenGL?

Tags: java, opengl, opengl-compat

I need to understand can I call glBegin, glEnd, for my project just one time.

I tried to call myRender function one time, not for every tick, but it delets all polygons, on second frame.

My tick event

```
public void render() {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
        glClearColor(0.925f, 0.98f, 0.988f, 1f);

        glPushMatrix();
        game.tickRender();
        glPopMatrix();
    }
```

I tried this

```
public void render() { 
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
        glClearColor(0.925f, 0.98f, 0.988f, 1f);
    }
```

```
public void begin(){
        glPushMatrix();
        game.tickRender();
        glPopMatrix();
}
```

I need to calc myMatrix one time, for project optimization. Also if i can do it, i have second question. Can i draw static polygons one time, and non-static (moving) polygons in render function every tick?

Comment: What do you even mean by "Push your matrix"? The code doesn't show any matrix calculations. `glBegin/End` is basically outdated since decades, we have vertex arrays in VBOs since 15 years. Also, I don't know what you expect to see besides a solid color if you clear the window to a solid color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that drawing by [`glBegin`/`glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) sequences and the fixed function matrix stack is deprecated since decades. See [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) and [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL).
Read about [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) and [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) for a state of the art way of rendering.

---

[`glBegin`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) starts a sequence of [Primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive) and `glEnd` ends the sequence.
Of course you can draw multiple sequences of primitives in your code.

The vertex coordinates of the primitives are set by [`glVertex`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml). Each vertec coordinate is transformed by the current model view and projection matrix (see [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml)).

But note it is not allowed to change the current matrix within a `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequence. The only allowed commands after `glBegin` (and before `glEnd`) are the commands  which set the vertex coordinate and set thee corresponding attributes like `glVertex`, `glColor`, `glNormal`, `glTexCoord`...

The instructions like [`glColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml), [`glNormal`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glNormal.xml), [`glTexCoord`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexCoord.xml) ... change the current attributes, which is associated with the vertex when `glVertex` is called. This instructions can be performed before a `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequence, too.